# Growl iCal invite notification

Tags: ical, notifications

Is it possible to integrate Growl into iCal so that invitations made by other users are shown by Growl especially those which are pending?

Alternatives to show iCal notifications are also welcome!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Whoops, didn't know that such a simple interface was able to show notifications

ANSWER: iCal is able to display invitations out of the box

[image]

[image]